# I a table Trn_Clear having columns [SplitUpKey]       ,[Clr_Key]       ,[FeeComponent]       ,[Amt]

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

In this table, column `FeeComponent` contains three types of value suppose `a`, `b`, `c` and regarding `Amt` having price.

```
   A   40 
   A   20
   B   30
   B   20
   B   40
   c   60
```

Now I want Result in the form of a table like

```
A,B,C
```

`Amount` by `FeeComponent`-wise.
It's a single Table.

I tried Something like:

```
Select 
    (Select Amt from Trn_Clear where Amt='A') As 'A1',
    (Select Amt From Trn_Clear where Amt='B') As 'B1' 
From  Trn_Clear
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that what you wanna do is to pivot your table; in that case, if you are using SQL Server 2005, you should try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT FeeComponent, Amt FROM Trn_Clear) AS S
PIVOT(SUM(Amt) FOR FeeComponent IN ([A],[B],[C])) AS PT
```

In this case, I use `SUM` as your aggregation function, but you could use the one you need (`AVG`,`MIN`,`MAX`). Hope this helps.